# What versions of the OS X support Safari 6?

Tags: macos, mac, safari

Our webapp requires Safari 6.0 or higher. What versions of OS X support Safari 6 or higher?

Answer (score 2):

Safari 6 can be run on OS's Lion and Mountain Lion. The initial release of the browser was for Mountain Lion as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Safari_6).

Answer (score 2):

Safari 6 was included with OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 and also available from Safari 6.1 on OS X Lion 10.7.5 (note the point release number for OS X Lion, since the previous version of OS X Lion, 10.7.4, was updated with Safari 5.1.4).

Here's the relevant information from the Apple KB titled [How to install Safari 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6103):

> - Safari 6 is included with OS X Mountain Lion v10.8 and later and can be updated to Safari 6.1 using Software Update
> - Safari 6.1 is available from Software Update for OS X Lion v10.7.5
>
> If you don't see Safari 6 when you use Software Update, try applying other updates first. For example, OS X Lion users must update to v10.7.5 before Safari 6.1 can be installed.